# Read JSON Multipart request in php

Tags: php, json

Android is sending data to server in JSON format. It includes image files in request. Request type is multi-part.

I tried below. but no luck.

```
function  readInputStream() {
    $return_array = array();
    $body = @file_get_contents('php://input');
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) 
    {
        $body = stripslashes($body);
    }
    // check if body is compressed or not
    if (strlen($body) < 18 || strcmp(substr($body,0,2),"\x1f\x8b")) 
    {
        $body = $body;
    } 
    else 
    {
        $tbody = $this->gzdecode($body);
        $body = $tbody;
    }
    if(!empty($body)) 
    {
        $return_array = json_decode($body, true);
    }

    return $return_array;

}
```

I tried this with $_POST method , It works with that but want to know what wrong in above code.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have is for parsing a JSON request body.

You have a Multipart request body.

Multipart can **contain** JSON but it isn't JSON itself.